# Appending to JSON string in Scala for Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to fix a function due to a PR merge in the latest Spark version causing a previous Spark method to no longer exist, and having some issues. Here is the code snippet:

```
protected def logSparkListenerEvent(
                                   event: SparkListenerEvent,
                                   getTimestamp: () => Instant =
                                   () => Instant.now()): Unit = {
val json = try {
  // Add a well-known time field.
  Some( {
    val eventJsonString = JsonProtocol.sparkEventToJsonString(event)
    val eventJsonStringParsed = Json.parse(eventJsonString)
    val eventJsonStringAppendedData = Json.obj(SparkInformation.get() + ("SparkEventTime" -> getTimestamp().toString))
    val eventJsonStringCombined = eventJsonStringParsed.as[JsObject] ++ eventJsonStringAppendedData
    val eventJsonStringUpdated = Json.stringify(eventJsonStringCombined)
})
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    logError(s"Error serializing SparkListenerEvent to JSON: $event", e)
    None
}

sendToSink(json)
```

}

I am using the Scala JSON Play library to try to do this.

When I try to build the project via Maven, it errors out with the following:

```
[ERROR] C:/spark-monitoring-main/src/spark-listeners/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/listeners/UnifiedSparkListener.scala:73: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
 required: (String, play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper)
[ERROR] C:/spark-monitoring-main/src/spark-listeners/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/listeners/UnifiedSparkListener.scala:83: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Unit]
 required: Option[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]
[ERROR] two errors found
```

I am fairly new to Scala so it's a challenge. Any help on how I can fix this would be great!

This is the previous code block before my changes:

```
protected def logSparkListenerEvent(
                                       event: SparkListenerEvent,
                                       getTimestamp: () => Instant =
                                       () => Instant.now()): Unit = {
    val json = try {
      // Add a well-known time field.
      Some(
        JsonProtocol.sparkEventToJson(event)
          .merge(render(
            SparkInformation.get() + ("SparkEventTime" -> getTimestamp().toString)
          ))
      )
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        logError(s"Error serializing SparkListenerEvent to JSON: $event", e)
        None
    }

    sendToSink(json)
  }
```